# In Rails 5 Api, how do you match an error message to the request json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

Sorry if the question is hard understand, but let's say that i have a model `Post` with an has_many relation to `Comments` and some validation on the `Comments` model. Set up like this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 20}, uniqueness: true
    has_many :comments, inverse_of: :post
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    validates :message, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 20}, uniqueness: true
    belongs_to :post
end
```

When I create a new `Post`, i want to also create one or more`Comment`(s). *(odd, I know)*

I do it with this JSON, which have the `Comment`s in an object(instead of array) so that I can set some uuids to the `Comment`s and map it back in the frontend.

```
{
"post": {
        "comments_attributes": {
            "97b1770c-0798-41d9-9a6c-f31ffeb22048": {
                "title": ""
            },
            "244fbca6-4a73-44dc-8d9d-26cc169ee757": {
                "title": "The first wont pass validation"
            }
        },
        "title": "A title off a post, with prefilled comments(?!)"
    }
}
```

I take the params, permit check and then save it in the same fashion as I received them in, and then try to save. When the save fails i return

```
render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

the returing error message is like this:

```
"comments.title":["is too short (minimum is 3 characters)"]}
```

How can I associate which of the comments that where invalid?

Of course, a thing such as string length is something that can be handled in the frontend as well, but if it where something that required a unique input it would be more difficult to map it to what object in the JSON that i was suppose to save.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the  "comments_attributes" from your params
2. save the post without comments -> bail out if there are errors here
3. loop over your comments and try to add them one by one,
   all the while collecting the errors

Comment: shame... thought there was some rails magic here, since the api docs makes an example on how to use named hashes instead of an array... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html - search for "first: "

Comment: well, the magic for creating the resources is there.  it just seems to break down when it comes to error messages, doesn't it?